# Icon set for Android, with iPhone look

Tags: android, image

I've been asked to develop an App for both systems, Android and iPhone, and both must look the same. So, I would like to get a set of icons that look like the iPhone buttons.

Anybody knows a link where I can download/buy a set of .png to make the Android app look like the iPhone one? (In iPhone, im gonna use de default buttons)

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you find android like icons and make the iPhone look like android? Just kidding. My advice is to not give android users the iPhone experience.

Comment: I am an Android fan... but the boss is who rules :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before giving a few links to get you started, let me also include a link from Android's design guidelines followed by a quote from the same link:

[Pure Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)

> **Don't mimic UI elements from other platforms**
>
> Platforms typically provide a carefully designed set of UI elements
>   that are themed in a very distinctive fashion. For example, some
>   platforms advocate rounded corners for their buttons, others use
>   gradients in their title bars. In some cases, elements may have the
>   same purpose, but are designed to work a bit differently.

I am not sure if aping / mimicking the iPhone is the intention or the right way heading into multi-platform development (although I am inclined to think, based on the topic heading, that you intend to keep *just* a common icon base across platforms). But without getting into that debate and the proverbial can of worms. Anyway, here a few links as mentioned at the top:

**NOTE: I do not develop for the iOS platform and am not entirely aware of what the default icons are. If the links posted are useless, give me a heads up. ;-)**

1. http://www.glyphish.com/
2. http://www.designshock.com/free-iphone-icons/
3. http://www.iconshock.com/iphone-icons/
4. http://speckyboy.com/2008/07/18/35-free-icon-sets-for-your-iphone-pimp-it-up/
5. http://visionwidget.com/free-iphone-themes-icons-sets.html
6. http://ntt.cc/2010/05/10/50-free-hand-picked-iphone-icon-sets.html
7. http://www.tutorialchip.com/freebies/25-impressive-fantastic-icon-sets-for-your-iphone/
8. http://skyje.com/iphone-themes-and-icon-sets/
9. http://inspiredm.com/5-essential-icon-sets-for-iphone-applications/

The first link (*glyphish*) usually pops up all over Google when searching for mobile icons. Oh. They also support the Retina Display. :-)

Comment: If it would be my responsability, I wouldn't design the apps that way, but... I am only an employee, and the boss is who rules. Thank for your answer :)

Comment: @Fustigador: I know. That sucks. ;-) Glad to have helped. :-)

Comment: Siddharth, these links provide sets of icons, but not is exactly what i was looking for. Anyway, these are very interesting links. By the way, i convinced my boss to not mimic iPhone in the Android app ;)